# nsis installer: how to turn off 'verifying installer' box in silent mode?

Tags: windows, nsis

When running an nsis installer in silent mode, I want the CRCCheck to be performed, but I don't want it to pop up a box which says 'Verifying installer...". How do I avoid the pop up without disabling CRCheck?

Comment: Looks to me like it is not visible when silent. What is your NSIS version?

Comment: 3.01 . It is visible when the installer is huge, like ~500MB huge.